# Green function of symmetric stable process in dimension 1 and 2

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, semigroups-of-operators

Are the results in [this paper](https://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/%7Epms/files/17.2/Article/17.2.8.pdf) on the Green function of a symmetric stable process available also in space dimension $d =1$ and $d=2$? The main theorems here are stated only for $d \ge 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: see Corollary 1.2 in by Z.-Q. Chen *Heat kernel estimates for the Dirichlet fractional Laplacian*, [DOI:10.4171/JEMS/231](https://doi.org/10.4171/JEMS/231).

---

Long answer: Extension should be automatic as long as $\alpha < d$. When $\alpha \geqslant d = 1$, the estimates are available, too, but have a different form, because the underlying process is point-recurrent (when $\alpha > d = 1$), and because the potential kernel has a different form (when $\alpha = d = 1$).

For a discussion of the case $d \geqslant 2$, see, for example, *A note on the Green function estimates for symmetric stable processes* by Z.-Q. Chen and R. Song, [DOI:10.1142/9789812702241_0008](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812702241_0008). Note that the original estimate was found independently by T. Kulczycki in the paper *Properties of the Green function of symmetric stable processes* linked in the question, and by Z.-Q. Chen and R. Song in the paper *Estimates on Green  functions and Poisson kernels for symmetric stable processes*, [DOI:10.1007/s002080050232](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002080050232).

Off the top of my head, I do not know a reference that would cover $d = 1$ using purely potential-theoretic methods (although this case should be identical to the above when $\alpha < 1$, and much simpler when $\alpha \geqslant 1$). In the paper linked in the short answer above, the authors estimate the heat kernel first, and then integrate it with respect to time to get a bound for the Green function.

Answer (score 0):

I have obtained the closed form (as the integral of an elementary algebraic function) of the Green function on the unit interval for $\alpha$-stable processes with $1\leq \alpha\leq 2$  and  $0<\rho<1$.

I would like to know how much of it is known.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/173436)